# What's the purpose behind this phishing attempt?

Tags: email, phishing

As probably all of you, I got an email that was intended as a phishing attack.

The HTML version of the email was pretending to be a Facebook email of a security warning.

[image: phishing image]

The links do lead to Facebook, for an account-switching crafted URL. I get that one.

However, the text version of the email has something like this:

```
mailto:xxx@stanforduni.com;xxx@massachusettsins.co.uk;xxx@e-irosky.me;xxx@harvarduni.org;xxx@univofcambridge.eu;xxx@univofoxford.com;xxx@yandex.ru;xxx@yandex.ua;xxx@yandex.kz;xxx@yandex.by;xxx@yandex.com;xxx@mail.ru;xxx@yahoo.com;xxx@aol.com;xxx@gmail.com
```

(I redacted out usernames from those addresses.)

Some of those names seem to be related (maybe the same person across multiple domains?). Some others seem generic but on a similar vein (mostly universities).

**My question is: what's the purpose of this "attack"?** Clicking on those would trigger my email client to prepare an email for all those addresses. What does an attacker gain out of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the dangers of a mailto link?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235427/what-are-the-dangers-of-a-mailto-link)

Comment: This is likely a bug by the sender and not some kind of attack. I regular get mails where the spam/phishing template is not properly applied etc. Some spammers seem to be too stupid to use the tools they bought properly.

Comment: @nobody Absolutely, yes. Sorry, I promise I did my search and I did not find that answer. I obviously did not look well enough! Thanks again!

Comment: @Alpha That's actually fine. I wouldn't have found it either if I didn't remember about it, since it isn't immediately obvious what that question is about.